# How to phrase "I have always trusted and hopefully will always trust you"

Tags: sentence-construction

How would I phrase this sentence properly:

> I have, and hopefully will, always trusted (should I add a trust
>   here?) you

This is what I thought:

> I have always trusted and hopefully will always trust you.

Seems a little redundant though, any suggestions?

Comment: *I always have, and hopefully will continue to trust you.* If you're "sharing" the verb (*trust*, here), you make it agree with the last of the preceding elements (*will continue to*, here).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That sentence doesn't seem grammatical to me.

Comment: @snailplane: An awful lot of writers would still deplore such use of *hopefully* - but if I remove that, there are plenty of written instances of [*{subject} always have and will continue to {verb}*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22always+have+and+will+continue+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I agree it's a bit "klunky", but if you want something reasonably short it's probably about the best you can do. Presumably that's what those 5,340 writers thought, anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I count 15, FWIW, of which at least 5 are grammatical via post-auxiliary ellipsis after *have*.

Comment: @snailplane: I dunno what *post-auxiliary ellipsis* means there, but I see what you mean about the numbers. Well, I mean if I scroll through all the results it ends at 56, and prolly only 15 of them actually *display* the search term (why do the others appear in the first place?). On reflection, I like it less now than the little I did before. But I'm certainly not going to get bogged down in a grammatical/ungrammatical debate - to me it's just *clumsy*, but native speakers obviously can and do use it sometimes. It's not just a "bad translation" form.

Answer (score 1):

**Any of these should work:**

- I have always trusted you; and hopefully, I always will.
- I have always trusted you. And hopefully, I always will.

**This is more dramatic/emphatic: (and more common):**

- I have--and always will--trust you.

**You could also say this:**

- I have always trusted you.  And hopefully -- if you don't rob me or stab me in the back --  I always will.

Comment: "I have, and always will trust you."  How would you read this sentence? I have trust you. I always will trust you? This is where I was concerned.

Comment: There is a kind of similar issue with plurality.  John **was** there and the Robbinsons **were** there.  John and the Robinsons **were** there. (Also one might say "The Robinsons and John was there." But stylistically, it's most-often best to put the plural noun last and use the plural verb form.)

Comment: This is funny to me because there was recently a question about the "rule" of parallel sentence construction. I looked high and low for a sentence that would "break" that rule -- but to no avail. It seemed like a rock solid rule of style. But I think there's an argument that the pithiness of "I have, and always will trust you." can be justified as more dramatic than the weight gained by forcing a parallel construction.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I think repeating the verb twice in two different tenses reads better. For example,

> *I have (always) **trusted**, and hopefully will (be able to) continue to **trust**, you.*

It's just my opinion, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

> My trust in you is eternal.